# How to get available rooms from derby embedded database

Tags: sql, derby

I am building a hotel management system an I am stuck at finding the available rooms at specified date. I have two tables namely Rooms and Reservation

```
Rooms Table
| RoomID | Name | Floor | Bed | Rent | RoomType|

Reservation Table
| ResvID | RoomId | CheckIn | CheckOut | CustomerID |
```

And the Foreign key in reservation table is RoomId.

All I want is to get the room that is available (Not booked on given date). My Application also provides features to add new rooms. So just joining with Reservation table did not give me the desired result as the new rooms would never be in the reservation table. I also want to filter with BedType and RoomType. And I used the following query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT r.RoomID, r.RoomNo, r.Name, r.Floor, r.RoomType, r.Rent
 FROM hms.rooms r
 JOIN hms.reservation rv
   ON r.RoomID = rv.ROOM_ID
 WHERE (((rv.CHECKIN < ? AND  --Checkin Provided
         rv.CHECKOUT <= ?) OR  --Checkin Provided
         (rv.CHECKIN >= ? AND --Checkout Provided
         rv.CHECKOUT > ?)) AND --Checkout Provided
         rv.CHECKIN <> ? AND rv.CHECKOUT <> ?) AND  -- Checkin/Checkoutprovided
         (r.RoomType = ? AND  --RoomType provided
         r.Bed = ?)  --BedType provided
  UNION
  SELECT RoomID, RoomNo, Name, Floor, RoomType, Rent
  FROM hms.rooms AS r WHERE r.RoomID NOT IN(
  SELECT ROOM_ID FROM hms.reservation) AND
 (r.RoomType = ? AND r.Bed = ?)  --Room?BedType provided
```

And this query does not work. It always shows the room.

**Edit:** Tried this code but its still showing room as available

```
SELECT RoomID, RoomNo, Name, Floor, RoomType, Rent
  FROM hms.rooms r
WHERE r.RoomID NOT IN
 (SELECT ROOM_ID
    FROM hms.reservation rv
  WHERE(
       ((rv.CHECKIN <= ?) AND --in
        (rv.CHECKOUT  > ? AND rv.CHECKOUT < ?)) OR --in/out

        ((rv.CHECKIN < ? AND rv.CHECKIN > ?) AND --out/in
        (rv.CHECKOUT >= ?)) OR --out

        (rv.CHECKIN > ? AND rv.CHECKOUT < ?) OR --in/out

        (rv.CHECKIN = ? AND rv.CHECKOUT = ?) OR --in/out

        (rv.CHECKIN < ? AND  rv.CHECKOUT > ?) --in/out

    ) AND

    (r.RoomType = ? AND r.Bed = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some sample data and point out what is failing and what the expected results should be. If I understand correctly, you are trying to find a room that is not reserved for any time during a specified checkin-checkout range.  Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT RoomID, RoomNo, Name, Floor, RoomType, Rent
  FROM hms.rooms r
  WHERE r.RoomID NOT IN (SELECT ROOM_ID
                           FROM hms.reservation rv
                           WHERE rv.CHECKIN  < :p_checkout
                             AND rv.CHECKOUT > :p_checkin
                        )
    AND r.RoomType = :p_room_type AND r.Bed = :p_bed_type
```

i.e. if there is a reservation that starts before my checkout (`:p_checkout`) and is not completed before my checkin (`:p_checkin`), then exclude the reserved room from the list of available rooms.